# is there a way to combine 2 len(list) in 1 for loop

Tags: python

okay so basically I am doing turtle graphics in class, and there was a challenge to draw a night sky. I decided to draw stars on a dark blue screen. I also decided that I wanted the stars to be drawn randomly on the screen and that the stars should not overlap. My issue comes from checking that they don't overlap.

```
x_list=[]
y_list=[]
c = random.randint(-200,200)
d = random.randint(-200,200)
def makeStar():
 for i in range(5):
   t.speed(1)
   t.color(colour3)
   t.forward(50)
   t.right(144)

def star():
  c = random.randint(-200,200)
  d = random.randint(-200,200)
  t.penup()
  t.goto(c,d)
  x_list.append(t.xcor())
  y_list.append(t.ycor())
  def corCheck():
    **for i in len(list)**:
      while true: 
        if c <= x_list or c >= x_list:
          c=random.randint(-200,200)
        elif d <= y_list or d >= y_list:
          d=random.randint(-200,200)
        else: 
          break #or can be return false
  corCheck()
  t.goto(c,d)
  t.pendown()
  makeStar()
```

I worked on this with my teacher and we came up with this, but there is an error on the highlighted line. The error says "TypeError: object of type 'list' has no len() on line 122"
and I can't think of anything to fix that so any help will be very appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what do you expect to get by calling `len(list)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is a data type not a variable. I think you want to use one of your created lists.
Regarding to the title of the question, combining length of 2 lists, you can simply say: `for i in (len(first_list)+len(second_list)):`